# Running the ansible play on particular group of servers by taking the name of groups as input dynamically

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Lets say I have got inventory file like this
inventory.txt

```
abc
cde 
def 

[check1:children]
abc

[check2:children]
cde

[check3: children]
def
```

Now I will take input from user eg: `check1,check3` separated by comma in a variable and then I want to run my next play on those groups `check1,check3`.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A comma separated list of groups or hosts is [a perfectly valid pattern](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#common-patterns) for the hosts of a playbook.

So you can just pass it directly in the `hosts` attribute of your playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: "{{ user_provider_hosts }}"
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks:
    - debug:
```

Then, you just have to add this values in the `--extra-vars` (or short, `-e`) flag of the playbook command:

```sh
ansible-playbook play.yml --extra-vars "user_provider_hosts=check1,check3"
```

This would yield:

```
TASK [debug] ******************************************************************
ok: [abc] => 
  msg: Hello world!
ok: [def] => 
  msg: Hello world!
```

---

Another option is to target all hosts:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks:
    - debug:
```

And use the purposed [`--limit` flag](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#patterns-and-ansible-playbook-flags):

```sh
ansible-playbook play.yml --limit check1,check3
```

---

A third option would be to use a play targeting `localhost` to prompt the user for the groups to target, then use a fact set by `localhost` to target those groups in another play:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars_prompt:
    - name: _hosts
      prompt: On which hosts do you want to act? 
      private: no

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        user_provider_hosts: "{{ _hosts }}"

- hosts: "{{ hostvars.localhost.user_provider_hosts }}"
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks:
    - debug:
```

Would interactively ask for hosts and act on the user provider hosts:

```
On which hosts do you want to act?: check1,check3

PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ***************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY [check1,check3] **********************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************
ok: [abc] => 
  msg: Hello world!
ok: [def] => 
  msg: Hello world!
```